# Permanently disable foreign key checks for MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, foreign-keys

I´ve setup a data warehouse based on MariaDB. There for i created seperate databases for the stages my data is going through. I want to permanently disable the foreign key checks for two of these stages, even when i restart the server.
I know that `SET GLOBAL` dose not do the trick. For a permanent effect i need to change it in a config file but according to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108509/mysql-server-wont-start-with-foreign-key-checks-0) post you cannot use `foreign_key_checks` in the my.cnf.
So is there a way to achive this?

Comment: Are these `stages` in a script or something?

Comment: Every stage is a seperate database. The data is transferred between the stages/databases with Pentaho Data Integration (PDI).

Comment: I don't know PDI, but can you not add a ` SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` before the 2 stages that need it, and then set it back to 1 at the end of the stage where used?

Comment: Yes, thats sadly not the most comfortable way because there are many "scrips" in already in place but that would do the trick. So i guess there is no convenient way to disable the foreign key checks permanently for MariaDB?